# Google Places autocomplete according to selected city

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

I want to show the autocomplete based on the selected city in select option type is there any way to perform this task or show the error when the user select the different location that is not match to the selected cities

My code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Map</title>
  <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">  
<select name="city" id="city">
    <option value="Karnal">Karnal</option>
    <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
    <option value="Banglore">Banglore</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="location" id="location">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD2WulC6fdCHMwJUypDOiEWUstYLT2iXxQ&v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places,geometry"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {

$('#city').on('change', function() {
  var city = $('#city').val();
  alert(city);
})

var input = document.getElementById('location');
var options = {
  types: ['(regions)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: "ind"}
 };

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict for country by using:

```
componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
```

**But there is no way to restrict the results to just `cities`**, but this will largely achieve what you want. If you set yourBounds correctly, maybe limited to the area of a city, it will get you as close as currently possible.

Ex:

```
var input = document.getElementById( 'searchTextField' );
var options = {
  bounds: yourBounds,
  types: ['geocode']
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( input, options );
```

Comment: is there way to show error when the user choose different locality that is not match to the selected city like http://nobroker.in

Comment: You have to implement some custom logic for that

Comment: There is also [issue 4433](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4433). Please star it to let Google know that you are interested in this feature request.